# How should I add attribute after redirect to a controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am just a newbie about Spring.

I am now using `@ExceptionHandler` to handle all the exception for my web application. And after I catch the exception, it will go to and error.jsp page displaying the error message.

I have a `ParentController` and in that, I have:

```
    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(PortalException.class)
    public ModelAndView handle(PortalException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();

        map.addAttribute("message", e.getMessage());

        return new ModelAndView("/error", map);
    }
```

and I have a `ErrorController`extends the `ParentController` to add the attributes:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController extends ParentSecureController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String errorHandler(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("excetpion.message", request.getParameter("message"));
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

In the `error.jsp`:

```
<p>Excpetion is: ${exception.message}</p>
```

When I run my application, I can catch the exception and jump to `error.jsp`, but no exception message is display.
Anyone can help me to figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try use:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController extends ParentSecureController {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseBody
     public String errorHandler(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {
           map.put("excetpion.message", request.getParameter("message"));
           return "/error";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Map you get it messae from @Controller to View in this case error.jsp

**I hope these helped! :)**

Comment: Hi Hekomobile, it doesn't work for me. Actually I think I need to redirect from ParentController to ErrorController, and then in ErrorController to add the attributes.

Comment: Hi @Mike I update my answer, the collection Map get it object message from your Controller to view.